# IE11 webmail issues with touch, Chrome seems not to have

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, internet-explorer, tablet, touchscreen

So my company is starting to experiment with giving users tablets (Windows 8.1, Dell Venue 11 tablets). And I'm running into an issue with our webmail application. On a desktop, you'd normally have to double-click an email to open it. But when using IE11, touble-tapping just zooms in the page. Somehow, Chrome opens the mail links with one click, I have no idea how. So our workaround are to have users use Chrome (while many other web apps require IE, so switching around is no preferred) or long-press to get an Open dialog to open the email. I've found that MS offers CSS changes to disable the double-tap to zoom functionality, but I've been told changes to the webmail app are unlikely.

Is there any way to either a. get Chrome's functionality into IE where a single-click works, or b. disable just IE11's double-tap to zoom functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: You would have to change the webmail. IE and Chrome handle touch differently.  Have you just tried single tapping the email?  Thats how it works on iOS.

Comment: Single-tapping just high-lights the email. And yes, I figure it's going to take the webdevs making changes to make it more functional with touch. But this is a huge company and that probably won't happen anytime soon since tablets aren't a big thing yet.

Comment: What webmail are we talking about exactly?  I know its not OWA.

Comment: is your webmail platform based on .Net 4.0? There is an ASP bug with IE10+ where linkbutton controls (and several other types like radio buttons) do not post back to the server when activated, so the link is never followed. if you confirm that that is the problem, you can address that by installing this patch on the webserver. http://hotfixv4.microsoft.com/.NET%20Framework%204.0%20-%20Windows%20XP,%20Windows%202003,%20Windows%20Vista,%20Windows%20Server%202008,%20Win7,%20Windows%20Server%202008%20R2%20(MSI)/nosp/DevDiv953277/30319.504/free/436907_intl_x64_zip.exe